# How to make all tooltips semi-transparent in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, transparency

I've managed to make semi-transparent tooltips using UIManager and creating Colors with 4 parameters:

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background",new Color(0x40,0x51,0x67,0x40));
```

But there's a problem - well, two in fact: the first tooltip that appears on the screen always ignores the transparency, and - unfortunately - same goes for tooltips outside of the window frame. From what I can understand (and judging from the only piece of information I could find), this is because some of the tooltips are heavyweight rather than lightweight and that's why their ignore my color setting for some reason. While I could manage to keep my stuff with tooltips far enough from the border, it seems like a cheap way to solve this problem and it still doesn't cover the first tooltip appearing white for some reason.

So, a clueless newbie asks: is there a simple way to make heavyweight tooltips transparent without making my own classes extending PopupFactory and Popup? If there isn't, do you have any tips on what I should change if I decide to create new classes and replace default PopupFactory with:

```
PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(new MyPopupFactory());
```

Also, out of sheer curiosity and since it concerns tooltips: why does this...

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background",new Color(0x40,0x51,0x67);
```

...replace both ToolTip.background and ToolTip.backgroundInactive, while when I use ColorUIResource I have to write two separate commands:

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background",new ColorUIResource(0x60,0x6a,0x76));
UIManager.put("ToolTip.backgroundInactive",new ColorUIResource(0x60,0x6a,0x76));
```

I know that my questions might have turned out a bit chaotic, but any advices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"..any advices would be greatly appreciated."*  Leave the tool-tips as solid color and invest the time allotted to that, into actual **improvements** to the app. (as opposed to 'kewl eye candy').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transparency not working as expected with a heavyweight component is normal - window transparency, although supported by some platforms, is not supported directly by swing.

You can make use of com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities (not portable to other VM's obviously) to make windows transparent (see this article: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html).

Take a look at the JRE source code of PopupFactory. You could call setPopupType(2) to make the factory prefer heavyweight popups. The method is not visible, so you will need to call it using reflection. Thats a hack you can't be sure it will work in future obviously.

Since Swing doesn't support it through its standard API, the most sensible choice would probably be to not use transparency effects where they are not supported. Possibly don't use transparency at all, if you desire a uniform look.